# RQL query to search for a string in comma separated column value

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

My table column `data-type` is `String`. It contains values like `a;b;c`, `d;e;f` and so on. This means that all values are separated by a `;`. I am looking for the values `b` and `f`. Please suggest a query will return rows containing `a;b;c` and `d;e;f` using query builder.

Comment: if you are good at SQL query you can go for SqlPassthroughQuery https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/RepositoryGuide/html/s0803overridingrqlgeneratedsql01.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into the out-of-the-box implementations of the `atg.repository.servlet.SearchFormHandler` and what it can do for you. That said, your query is likely going to require some string manipulation and may look like this:

`fieldName STARTS_WITH ?';' OR fieldName CONTAINS ';'?';' OR fieldName ENDS_WITH ';'?`

The above may need to be built up in your JAVA code using a `StringBuffer` to ensure that the `?` input string (eg. `b` or `f`) is correctly quoted with the `;` marks. Not sure if you'll be able to do this as a property file outside of JAVA.

The above should work but also can't guarantee the speed.

You may also need to add `_IGNORE_CASE` to the respective operators but you didn't specify the need in your question.